# Mock JSON file consumed by the constructor of a class with Jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, ts-jest

The constructor function of my class is consuming an imported JSON file. I need to mock this file and use another JSON file that has data for testing purposes only.

```
// myClass.ts
import * as myData from '../data.json';

export class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.data = [...myData];
  }

  getData() {
    return this.data;
  }
}
```

```
// myClass.test.ts
import { MyClass } from '../myClass.ts';
import * as myTestData from '../__mocks__/data.json';

describe('MyClass', () => {
  let myClass: MyClass;

  beforeEach(() => {
     myClass = new MyClass();

  // How can I modify the constructor so when I instantiate MyClass,
// it uses myTestData instead of the real data json file? 
  })
 

  
  ...
})
```

Any idea how to achieve this using Jest?

Comment: You can't normally mock a constructor because a constructor is a class itself in JS. But you can mock a module it depends on, `jest.mock('../data.json')`

Comment: @EstusFlask you're right. It was easier than I thought, I just need to mock the JSON file for it to work. Thanks

Comment: @FelipeRueda, How were you able to JSON file. I am trying to mock it using `jest.mock` with the same file path as defined in my component (myClass.ts, in this case) but it still uses the same JSON file as imported in the component (myClass.ts)